# How can I get `git log` to append ellipsis after the commit subject line if the message body is non-empty?

Tags: git, git-log

E.g. suppose this is what my git history looks like:

```
$ git log --oneline
f9b86d3 (HEAD -> main) blah the baz
966a640 foobar the frob
ac27e4d Revert "do something special"
338ff0f do something special
...
```

However suppose `966a640` and `ac27e4d` have additional lines in their commit message bodies. (`f9b86d3` and `338ff0f` are just the subject lines / have empty bodies.)

How can I make a git log [format specifier](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) that appends an ellipsis to the end of the subject line ONLY IF there is additional text in the body?

E.g. I'd like the output to look like this:

```
$ $ git log --abbrev-commit --pretty='%h%d %s ???'
f9b86d3 (HEAD -> main) blah the baz
966a640 foobar the frob ...
ac27e4d Revert "do something special" ...
338ff0f do something special
...
```

---

I've found `%<([n],trunc)` and I can *almost* get there using `%<(1,trunc)% b` (with `%b` being the commit message body, and the space in the middle prepending a space if non-empty), but while that *does* correctly add a two-character ellipses, it unfortunately appears to preserve (only) the newlines from the body:

```
$ git log --abbrev-commit --pretty='%h%d %s%<(1,trunc)% b'
f9b86d3 (HEAD -> main) blah the baz
966a640 foobar the frob ..




ac27e4d Revert "do something special" ..


338ff0f do something special
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close! To trim the extra newlines from `%<(1,trunc)% b` you can use `%-` followed by a placeholder that's guaranteed to be empty.

From [https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#:%7E:text=If%20you%20add%20a%20%2D%20(minus%20sign)%20after%20%25%20of%20a%20placeholder%2C%20all%20consecutive%20line%2Dfeeds%20immediately%20preceding%20the%20expansion%20are%20deleted%20if%20and%20only%20if%20the%20placeholder%20expands%20to%20an%20empty%20string.):

> If you add a `-` (minus sign) after `%` of a placeholder, all consecutive line-feeds immediately preceding the expansion are deleted if and only if the placeholder expands to an empty string.

You can do this by requesting a commit "trailer" with a key that doesn't exist, i.e. `%-(trailers:key=x-always-empty)`.

All together:

```
$ git log --abbrev-commit --pretty='%h%d %s%<(1,trunc)% b%-(trailers:key=x-always-empty)'
f9b86d3 (HEAD -> main) blah the baz
966a640 foobar the frob ..
ac27e4d Revert "do something special" ..
338ff0f do something special
```